# Setting a pygame surface to have rounded corners

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, blending

This `Rectangle` class extends from pygame.sprite.  I'd like to use `set_rounded` to modify how round the corners of the rect are.  For example https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyKWC.jpg

```py
class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pg.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def set_rounded(self, roundness):
        pass
```

The `roundness` argument would determine the radius of the rounded rect.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: I requested an edit because the wrong index was being used for the rectangle's width. The other issue is that the background of the rounded rect is black, not transparent.  This can be seen by changing the colour of the background.

Comment: @Rabbid76 There still seems to be the issue of the self.rect_image surface, which is still displaying for some reason behind the rect.  Change the window background to window.fill((0, 150, 0)).  I haven't been able to find a solution to this.  I tried setting the alpha, changing its visibility, but it still persists.

Comment: You are right, there was a bug in my answer (beginner mistake). I've corrected the answer:  `self.image = self.original_image.copy().convert_alpha()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by setting the key word argument `border_radius` of the function [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect).

Create a rectangle the same size as the image and and per pixel alpha (`SRCALPHA`) and draw a completely white, opaque image with round corners on it:

```py
size = self.original_image.get_size()
self.rect_image = pg.Surface(size, pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.rect(self.rect_image, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size), border_radius=roundness)
```

Copy the original image and use the `BLEND_RGBA_MIN` blending mode to blend the rectangle with the image (see [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)):

```py
self.image = self.original_image.copy().convert_alpha()
self.image.blit(self.rect_image, (0, 0), None, pg.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

**Note, the keyword attribute `border_radius` is a new feature in Pygame 2.0.**

---

If you can't use version 2.0, you'll need to stick the rounded rectangle together yourself:

```py
class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def set_rounded(self, roundness):
        size = self.original_image.get_size()
        self.rect_image = pg.Surface(size, pg.SRCALPHA)
        
        #pg.draw.rect(self.rect_image, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size), border_radius=roundness)

        r, c = roundness, (255, 255, 255)
        pg.draw.rect(self.rect_image, c, (r, 0, size[0]-2*r, size[1]))
        pg.draw.rect(self.rect_image, c, (0, r, size[0], size[1]-2*r))
        for cpt in [(r, r), (size[0]-r, r), (r, size[1]-r), (size[0]-r, size[1]-r)]:  
            pg.draw.circle(self.rect_image, c, cpt, r)

        self.image = self.original_image.copy().convert_alpha()
        self.image.blit(self.rect_image, (0, 0), None, pg.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

---

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame as pg

class Rectangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pg.Surface((100, 100))
        self.original_image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_rounded(self, roundness):
        size = self.original_image.get_size()
        self.rect_image = pg.Surface(size, pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.rect(self.rect_image, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, *size), border_radius=roundness)

        self.image = self.original_image.copy().convert_alpha()
        self.image.blit(self.rect_image, (0, 0), None, pg.BLEND_RGBA_MIN) 

pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode((200, 200))

rect_object = Rectangle()
rect_object.set_rounded(30)
rect_object.rect.center = window.get_rect().center
group = pg.sprite.Group(rect_object)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((128, 128, 128))
    group.draw(window)
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: This project has to be compatible with pygame 1.9.6+.  Is there a way to achieve this without using border_radius?

Comment: @Hydra I've extended the answer.