# draw lines with round edges in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, line

how do I draw something like this in pygame without images:

[image: line with round edges]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700231/setting-a-pygame-surface-to-have-rounded-corners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a circles at the each end of the line. However, the quality is not that good. You need to tweak the with of the line ot the radius of the circle. You can get a better result by using [`pygame.draw.polygon`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) to draw a thick line. The best result you can get with [*opencv-python*](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and [`cv2.line()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2). See also [Drawing Functions in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html):

In the following example the red line is the line drawn with `pygame.draw.line` the orange line is drawn with `pygame.draw.polygon` and the yellow line is the line drawn with *OpenCV*:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import cv2, numpy

def draw_line_round_corners(surf, p1, p2, c, w):
    pygame.draw.line(surf, c, p1, p2, w)
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, c, p1, w // 2)
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, c, p2, w // 2)

def draw_line_round_corners_polygon(surf, p1, p2, c, w):
    p1v = pygame.math.Vector2(p1)
    p2v = pygame.math.Vector2(p2)
    lv = (p2v - p1v).normalize()
    lnv = pygame.math.Vector2(-lv.y, lv.x) * w // 2
    pts = [p1v + lnv, p2v + lnv, p2v - lnv, p1v - lnv]
    pygame.draw.polygon(surf, c, pts)
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, c, p1, round(w / 2))
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, c, p2, round(w / 2))

def draw_line_round_corners_cv(surf, p1, p2, color, w):
    rect = pygame.Rect(*p1, p2[0]-p1[0], p2[1]-p1[1])
    rect.normalize()
    rect.inflate_ip(w, w)
    line_image = numpy.zeros((rect.height, rect.width, 4), dtype = numpy.uint8)
    c = pygame.Color(color)
    line_image = cv2.line(line_image, (w//2, w//2), (p2[0]-p1[0]+w//2, p2[1]-p1[1]+w//2), (c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a), thickness=w)
    line_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(line_image.flatten(), rect.size, 'RGBA')
    surf.blit(line_surface, line_surface.get_rect(center = rect.center))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    draw_line_round_corners(window, (50, 50), (300, 300), "red", 20)
    draw_line_round_corners_polygon(window, (50, 100), (250, 350), "orange", 20)
    draw_line_round_corners_cv(window, (100, 50), (350, 250), "yellow", 20)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw a line, and then two circles at the ends:

```
pygame.draw.line(surface, color, start, end, width)
pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, start, width/2)
pygame.drae.circle(surface, color, end, width/2)
```